# Using Brisk or not?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, brisk

I will develop a scalable web application with lots of data. I am thinking of using Brisk. Has anyone ever used it? There are some good resources explaining how to use it but still it seems very new and have limited amount of sources (even in stackoverflow there is less than 10 questions about brisk:)

My question is, i will probably try to link other tools with Brisk especially for visiualisation of the data and other needs that I cannot foresee right now. And I am thinking of programming with Python. And for instance there is a python library to access cassandra but as far as i know there no library to access Brisk. So, would it be a problem when I try to add-on or merge other tools with Brisk?

Do you recommend using Brisk? Or going with native implementation of cassandra+hadoop+hive is a better choice without using Brisk?

Thanks.

EDIT: Does Brisk a commercial product? Which means open source version will not be updated again?

Answer (score 1):

I used Brisk a long time ago then tested Datastax Enterprise (DSE) and finally migrated away from Hadoop in favor of a custom map/reduce solution developed internally.

Brisk is an open source projects but after Datastax directed their efforts to a commercial offering, nobody is updating Brisk.

I suppose using Brisk is fine if you update cassandra, hadoop  and hive to more up-to-date versions and get the lastest Hive Cassandra Handler from [DataStax github](https://github.com/riptano/hive).

Even if you manage to use Brisk to your project, I recommend that you contact DataStax about their product offering. Current versions of DSE are a huge step forward from Brisk and may not cost too much.

If DSE is not an option to you and Brisk cannot help either, use the Hive Cassandra Handler I mentioned in a regular Hive/Hadoop/Cassandra instalation.